# Inbound emails using mailgun

Tags: php, email, mailgun

I am sending email using the mailgun API

```
`$result = $mg->sendMessage($domain, array(
  'from'    => 'Test Sender <sender@gmail.com>',
  'to'      => 'receiver@gmail.com',
  'subject' =>  'test mail',
  'html'    =>  'test message',
  )
);`
```

The mail is delivered successfully.I have configured a route in the mailgun but it is not working.How do I receive mails using mailgun when a user replies to the mail sent via API?

Comment: This may help https://help.mailgun.com/hc/en-us/articles/203068714-How-do-I-track-which-email-a-recipient-has-replied-to-

Comment: when the mail is replied it points to the message-id generated by gmail(sender and receiver both uses gmail lets suppose).But the sent mail is having message-id of mailgun.